# Using map2_dfr to bind_cols of data together

Tags: r

I have two lists called `5` and `6` which look like the following:

df1:

```
$`5`
$`5`$`2016-01-01`
            [,1]
 [1,] -0.8357399
 [2,]  0.7793535
 [3,]  1.2425095
 [4,]  1.0564501
 [5,]  0.7351215
 [6,] -0.1976808
 [7,]  0.1692951
 [8,] -0.4280740
 [9,] -0.5507262
[10,]  1.0437385

$`5`$`2016-01-02`
             [,1]
 [1,]  0.68302631
 [2,]  1.16508889
 [3,]  1.04583836
 [4,]  0.71979517
 [5,] -0.14236742
 [6,]  0.07792941
 [7,] -0.41616267
 [8,] -0.49082834
 [9,]  1.09706485
[10,]  1.06911635
```

Which are some predictions. I also have another list which looks like:

df2:

```
$`5`[[3]]
         date      wind     temp
1  2010-01-03  1.387097 42.09677
2  2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129
3  2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615
4  2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333
5  2010-01-07  8.774194 33.29032
6  2010-01-08  9.709677 32.25806
7  2010-01-09 12.419355 31.16129
8  2010-01-10  1.290323 27.54839
9  2010-01-11  2.258065 31.06452
10 2010-01-12  4.967742 33.83871

$`5`[[4]]
         date      wind     temp
1  2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129
2  2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615
3  2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333
4  2010-01-07  8.774194 33.29032
5  2010-01-08  9.709677 32.25806
6  2010-01-09 12.419355 31.16129
7  2010-01-10  1.290323 27.54839
8  2010-01-11  2.258065 31.06452
9  2010-01-12  4.967742 33.83871
10 2010-01-13  4.129032 40.70968
```

Which consists of some original data. I want to join the `df1` up with the `df2` so it will look something like:

```
$`5`[[3]]
         date      wind     temp   prediction
1  2010-01-03  1.387097 42.09677  -0.8357399
2  2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129   0.7793535
3  2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615   1.2425095 
4  2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333   1.0564501
5  2010-01-07  8.774194 33.29032   0.7351215
6  2010-01-08  9.709677 32.25806  -0.1976808
7  2010-01-09 12.419355 31.16129   0.1692951
8  2010-01-10  1.290323 27.54839  -0.4280740
9  2010-01-11  2.258065 31.06452  -0.5507262
10 2010-01-12  4.967742 33.83871   1.0437385
```

and

```
$`5`[[4]]
         date      wind     temp   prediction
1  2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129   0.68302631
2  2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615   1.16508889
3  2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333   1.04583836
4  2010-01-07  8.774194 33.29032   0.71979517
5  2010-01-08  9.709677 32.25806  -0.14236742
6  2010-01-09 12.419355 31.16129   0.07792941
7  2010-01-10  1.290323 27.54839  -0.41616267
8  2010-01-11  2.258065 31.06452  -0.49082834
9  2010-01-12  4.967742 33.83871   1.09706485
10 2010-01-13  4.129032 40.70968   1.09706485
```

Then finally I would like to bind all these lists together in a long format such as:

```
       date      wind     temp   prediction  ID
 2010-01-03  1.387097 42.09677  -0.8357399    5
 2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129   0.7793535    5
 2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615   1.2425095    5
 2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333   1.0564501    5
 2010-01-07  8.774194 33.29032   0.7351215    5
 2010-01-08  9.709677 32.25806  -0.1976808    5
 2010-01-09 12.419355 31.16129   0.1692951    5
 2010-01-10  1.290323 27.54839  -0.4280740    5
 2010-01-11  2.258065 31.06452  -0.5507262    5
 2010-01-12  4.967742 33.83871   1.0437385    5
 2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129   0.68302631   6
 2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615   1.16508889   6
 2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333   1.04583836   6
 2010-01-07  8.774194 33.29032   0.71979517   6
 2010-01-08  9.709677 32.25806  -0.14236742   6
 2010-01-09 12.419355 31.16129   0.07792941   6
 2010-01-10  1.290323 27.54839  -0.41616267   6
 2010-01-11  2.258065 31.06452  -0.49082834   6
 2010-01-12  4.967742 33.83871   1.09706485   6
 2010-01-13  4.129032 40.70968   1.09706485   6
```

Which is a large single data frame with the `ID` column being the list names.

I have tried with the following code:

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfr(df1, df2, ~map2_dfr(.x, map(.y, "date"), ~cbind(.x, date = .y)))
```

Which doesn't give what I am after.

```
# A tibble: 40 x 4
   `2016-01-01` `2016-01-02` `2016-01-03` `2016-01-04`
          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1       -0.836       0.683        1.12          0.935
 2        0.779       1.17         1.02          0.754
 3        1.24        1.05         0.776        -0.146
 4        1.06        0.720       -0.188         0.160
 5        0.735      -0.142        0.0884       -0.465
 6       -0.198       0.0779      -0.283        -0.543
 7        0.169      -0.416       -0.453         1.10 
 8       -0.428      -0.491        1.06          1.03 
 9       -0.551       1.10         1.03          0.976
10        1.04        1.07         1.06          1.29 
# … with 30 more rows
```

Data:

```
df1 <- list(`5` = list(`2016-01-01` = structure(c(-0.835739850997925, 
0.779353499412537, 1.24250948429108, 1.0564501285553, 0.735121548175812, 
-0.197680771350861, 0.169295132160187, -0.42807400226593, -0.550726175308228, 
1.04373848438263), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), `2016-01-02` = structure(c(0.683026313781738, 
1.16508889198303, 1.04583835601807, 0.719795167446136, -0.142367422580719, 
0.0779294073581696, -0.416162669658661, -0.490828335285187, 1.09706485271454, 
1.06911635398865), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), `2016-01-03` = structure(c(1.12009644508362, 
1.01791954040527, 0.775721669197083, -0.187799870967865, 0.0883594155311584, 
-0.283172011375427, -0.452982068061829, 1.06388020515442, 1.02800369262695, 
1.06038355827332), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), `2016-01-04` = structure(c(0.935240745544434, 
0.753606081008911, -0.145884394645691, 0.160260230302811, -0.464599192142487, 
-0.543198347091675, 1.10469722747803, 1.03225469589233, 0.976013004779816, 
1.28949522972107), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))), `6` = list(`2016-01-01` = structure(c(-1.05108523368835, 
0.831294775009155, 1.0468602180481, 1.4151725769043, 0.89024829864502, 
-0.23750251531601, 0.0968895554542542, -0.447583615779877, -0.885086059570312, 
1.16484880447388), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), `2016-01-02` = structure(c(0.898594379425049, 
1.03132367134094, 1.43809175491333, 1.05361354351044, -0.204488694667816, 
0.0889829993247986, -0.42036372423172, -0.906104445457458, 1.16317582130432, 
1.13032007217407), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), `2016-01-03` = structure(c(0.99635636806488, 
1.5137802362442, 0.92145836353302, -0.218990564346313, 0.147298634052277, 
-0.466208696365356, -0.896591305732727, 1.18873286247253, 1.10375666618347, 
1.59670341014862), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), `2016-01-04` = structure(c(1.45108199119568, 
0.860665202140808, -0.299971401691437, 0.0754360556602478, -0.460747301578522, 
-0.947231769561768, 1.06433939933777, 1.13789772987366, 1.70162570476532, 
2.04307699203491), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))))


df2 <- list(`5` = list(structure(list(date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 
14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619), class = "Date"), 
    wind = c(19.72, 3.19354838709677, 1.38709677419355, 3.2258064516129, 
    4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 9.70967741935484, 
    12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516), temp = c(41.6, 41.9677419354839, 
    42.0967741935484, 45.1612903225806, 47.3461538461538, 39.8333333333333, 
    33.2903225806452, 32.258064516129, 31.1612903225806, 27.5483870967742
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    date = structure(c(14611, 14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 
    14617, 14618, 14619, 14620), class = "Date"), wind = c(3.19354838709677, 
    1.38709677419355, 3.2258064516129, 4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 
    8.7741935483871, 9.70967741935484, 12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516, 
    2.25806451612903), temp = c(41.9677419354839, 42.0967741935484, 
    45.1612903225806, 47.3461538461538, 39.8333333333333, 33.2903225806452, 
    32.258064516129, 31.1612903225806, 27.5483870967742, 31.0645161290323
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    date = structure(c(14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 
    14618, 14619, 14620, 14621), class = "Date"), wind = c(1.38709677419355, 
    3.2258064516129, 4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 
    9.70967741935484, 12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516, 2.25806451612903, 
    4.96774193548387), temp = c(42.0967741935484, 45.1612903225806, 
    47.3461538461538, 39.8333333333333, 33.2903225806452, 32.258064516129, 
    31.1612903225806, 27.5483870967742, 31.0645161290323, 33.8387096774194
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    date = structure(c(14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 
    14619, 14620, 14621, 14622), class = "Date"), wind = c(3.2258064516129, 
    4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 9.70967741935484, 
    12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516, 2.25806451612903, 4.96774193548387, 
    4.12903225806452), temp = c(45.1612903225806, 47.3461538461538, 
    39.8333333333333, 33.2903225806452, 32.258064516129, 31.1612903225806, 
    27.5483870967742, 31.0645161290323, 33.8387096774194, 40.7096774193548
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")), `6` = list(
    structure(list(date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 14612, 14613, 
    14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619), class = "Date"), 
        wind = c(19.72, 3.19354838709677, 1.38709677419355, 3.2258064516129, 
        4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 
        9.70967741935484, 12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516), 
        temp = c(41.6, 41.9677419354839, 42.0967741935484, 45.1612903225806, 
        47.3461538461538, 39.8333333333333, 33.2903225806452, 
        32.258064516129, 31.1612903225806, 27.5483870967742)), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(14611, 
    14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620
    ), class = "Date"), wind = c(3.19354838709677, 1.38709677419355, 
    3.2258064516129, 4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 
    9.70967741935484, 12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516, 2.25806451612903
    ), temp = c(41.9677419354839, 42.0967741935484, 45.1612903225806, 
    47.3461538461538, 39.8333333333333, 33.2903225806452, 32.258064516129, 
    31.1612903225806, 27.5483870967742, 31.0645161290323)), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(14612, 
    14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14621
    ), class = "Date"), wind = c(1.38709677419355, 3.2258064516129, 
    4.19230769230769, 8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 9.70967741935484, 
    12.4193548387097, 1.29032258064516, 2.25806451612903, 4.96774193548387
    ), temp = c(42.0967741935484, 45.1612903225806, 47.3461538461538, 
    39.8333333333333, 33.2903225806452, 32.258064516129, 31.1612903225806, 
    27.5483870967742, 31.0645161290323, 33.8387096774194)), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(date = structure(c(14613, 
    14614, 14615, 14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14621, 14622
    ), class = "Date"), wind = c(3.2258064516129, 4.19230769230769, 
    8.08333333333333, 8.7741935483871, 9.70967741935484, 12.4193548387097, 
    1.29032258064516, 2.25806451612903, 4.96774193548387, 4.12903225806452
    ), temp = c(45.1612903225806, 47.3461538461538, 39.8333333333333, 
    33.2903225806452, 32.258064516129, 31.1612903225806, 27.5483870967742, 
    31.0645161290323, 33.8387096774194, 40.7096774193548)), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")))
```

**EDIT:**

I liked both solutions by @tmfmnk and @akrun.

(Some reasoning - mostly for me for coming back to this question at a later date)

On my full sample, I obtain the error `Error: Argument 2 must be length 2995920, not 2998110`. When I apply:

```
map2_dfr(map(df1, ~ bind_rows(.) %>%
              pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = "prediction") %>%
              select(-name)),
         map(df2, bind_rows),
         bind_cols, .id = "ID")
```

I narrowed the error down to the fact that:

```
map(df1, ~bind_rows(.) %>% 
      pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = "prediction") %>% 
      select(-name))
```

Creates 2 lists consisting of `2995920` observations. I also run separately;

```
map(processed_analysis, ~bind_rows(.))
```

Which creates 2 lists consisting of `2998110`. The difference of these two figures is `2190` (which I understand makes sense only to me but its significant since `2190` is the length of one of the list of lists or number of observations of one of the list of lists).

`2998110 / 2190 = 1369` where the `1369` is the number of list of lists I have in each of the lists (`5` and `6`) in this example.

@akrun's solution:

```
imap_dfr(df2, ~ bind_rows(.x) %>%
        mutate(ID = .y)) %>%
    mutate(prediction = unlist(df1)) %>%
    as_tibble
```

Gives me a data frame consisting of `5996220` observations. Which is the same as `2998110` + `2998110` or the number of observations each list `5` or `6` contains when the `1369` list of lists have been `rbind`'d.

The difference between @akrun solution of `2998110` and @tmfmnk solution of `2995920` is `2190` which is exactly the length of the number of rows of one of the `1369` list of lists for `5` and `6`.

`2998110 / 1369 = 2190` which is correct whereas `2995920 / 1369 = 2188..44` Which doesn't align with the data.

I do not understand why the two solutions seem to work perfectly on the data provided here and slightly differently on the full data I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option with `imap`.  As the `list` elements are of the same number of rows, it would be easier to `unlist` the first dataset and create a column 'prediction' after we bind the rows of the 'df2'

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap_dfr(df2, ~ bind_rows(.x) %>%
        mutate(ID = .y)) %>%
    mutate(prediction = unlist(df1)) %>%
    as_tibble
# A tibble: 80 x 5
#   date        wind  temp ID    prediction
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 2010-01-01 19.7   41.6 5         -0.836
# 2 2010-01-02  3.19  42.0 5          0.779
# 3 2010-01-03  1.39  42.1 5          1.24 
# 4 2010-01-04  3.23  45.2 5          1.06 
# 5 2010-01-05  4.19  47.3 5          0.735
# 6 2010-01-06  8.08  39.8 5         -0.198
# 7 2010-01-07  8.77  33.3 5          0.169
# 8 2010-01-08  9.71  32.3 5         -0.428
# 9 2010-01-09 12.4   31.2 5         -0.551
#10 2010-01-10  1.29  27.5 5          1.04 
# … with 70 more rows
```

---

Or with `base R`, we can use `Map` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(df2, do.call, what = rbind)
transform(do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, lst1, ID = names(lst1)), 
  make.row.names = FALSE)), prediction = unlist(df1, use.names = FALSE))
#         date      wind     temp ID  prediction
#1  2010-01-01 19.720000 41.60000  5 -0.83573985
#2  2010-01-02  3.193548 41.96774  5  0.77935350
#3  2010-01-03  1.387097 42.09677  5  1.24250948
#4  2010-01-04  3.225806 45.16129  5  1.05645013
#5  2010-01-05  4.192308 47.34615  5  0.73512155
#6  2010-01-06  8.083333 39.83333  5 -0.19768077
#...
```

Comment: I select this as the "answer" however I really liked the other answer by @tmfmnk also. I added justification & reasoning to the original question (mostly for myself should I need to come back and revisit this part of the problem I as having). Thanks again!

Comment: @user113156. One difference I find is the values in 'prediction' column (if you check the second value - it is 0.779 (as in your expected output)

Comment: @user113156 Is there any chance for one of the `list` elements to be `NULL`

Comment: I believe your solution gives me the correct answer. I am just a little confused as to why the final solutions for both answers given by yourself and @tmfmnk give me ever so slightly different results. I corrected for missing values previously in my code, also the ML model I used to make the predictions cannot use `NA` as the Y prediction value. My "guess" is that either the first list of lists or last list of list (which consists of `2190` observations) gets "ignored" by @tmfmnk code. However I cannot be 100% certain of this.

Comment: @user113156 could be that the `pivot_longer` step is removing some rows.  Not sure in the case of your original data

Comment: Yes I think it is something happening at the `pivot_longer` part of the code. It is a shame I cannot provide the full data as its quite large.

Comment: @user113156 it is okay.  anyway, `unlist` would be faster here

Comment: I checked it, it is not entirely returning the desired output. I modified my code to produce the expected output. @akrun, if you feel that it is using your approach, then I can remove it.

Comment: @tmfmnk No, you can keep it.  I replied only because the OP commented on my post.  I am just curious why your method with `pivot_longer` didn't work.  Is it because it is ordering differently

Comment: Sure, I appreciate it as it helped to discover this mistake of mine. Also, a nice post :) The core of the problem was (for the sample dataset), as you say, in the ordering. On the other hand, I don't know what could be wrong on the OPs real dataset.

Answer (score 6):

One option could be:

```
map2_dfr(map(df1, ~ unlist(.) %>%
              enframe(value = "prediction") %>%
              select(-name)),
         map(df2, bind_rows),
         bind_cols, .id = "ID")

   ID    prediction date        wind  temp
   <chr>      <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 5         -0.836 2010-01-01 19.7   41.6
 2 5          0.779 2010-01-02  3.19  42.0
 3 5          1.24  2010-01-03  1.39  42.1
 4 5          1.06  2010-01-04  3.23  45.2
 5 5          0.735 2010-01-05  4.19  47.3
 6 5         -0.198 2010-01-06  8.08  39.8
 7 5          0.169 2010-01-07  8.77  33.3
 8 5         -0.428 2010-01-08  9.71  32.3
 9 5         -0.551 2010-01-09 12.4   31.2
10 5          1.04  2010-01-10  1.29  27.5
# … with 70 more rows
```